Configuring a Project with FTXUI in Visual Studio Code
I've been struggling to install the FTXUI library for use in my project. I am using Visual Studio Code, and it seems like there is no guide out there for my particular case even in the documentation.
Tried:
I went through the documentation page and also the GitHub page of the project on installing the FTXUI. With no dedicated section for that, I assumed that installing it would require me to download the packages using either of these methods: "Multiple packages: CMake FetchContent (preferred), vcpkg, pkgbuild, conan." I cannot use CMake as my project can only use a standalone Makefile, and I tried using vcpkg but cannot seem to get it work in Visual Studio Code. With the following error,
error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance Could not locate a complete Visual Studio instance
Expectation:
I want to install FTXUI in my project repository such that I can link it statically.

I used these flags to compile with gcc:
g++ -IFTXUI/include -LFTXUI/build [cpp file] -lftxui-component -lftxui-dom -lftxui-screen

where FTXUI contains the clone of the repo.

A few follow up questions, I hope you don't mind.


Did you clone the whole repository (incl. the cmake and example folders)? Either way, did you clone it within your own project directory?


What does the [cpp file] refer to?


Apologies if these questions are too basic, I'm a beginner to C++

Sure. 1. I did clone the repository, indeed, but I didn't clone it in my project directory; the flags used (-I, and -L) helped me in this case since they allow to tell the compiler where to additionally look for header files (-I) and libraries (-L). 2. [cpp file] is a placeholder denoting the file to compile, the [ ] brackets are used in e.g. man pages for placeholders. No worries, it's all good.

@bruinomust, friendly nudge, did the answers help?

I can suggest using the ftxui Conan package for this (https://conan.io/center/recipes/ftxui).
Here's a basic conanfile.txt to consume the package:
[requires]
ftxui/5.0.0

[options]
ftxui/*:shared=False

[layout]
cmake_layout

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

A "getting started" guide for Conan: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html
For a more seamless integration with CMake, you can include conan_provider.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan in your project.
The package can be consumed in CMake with
find_package(ftxui REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET ftxui::ftxui)

